# grub не видит windows 8

Tags: ubuntu

Установил убунту рядом с windows 8 (с убунту в первый раз ковыряюсь). Отщепил кусочек в 100 гигов от диска C, сделал 2 раздела на 16 гб под swap и 84 гб под систему. Вот так у меня все выглядит:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume1      2048   1230847   1228800   600M Windows  
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume2   1230848   1845247    614400   300M EFI Syst
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume3   1845248   2107391    262144   128M Microsof
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume4   2107392 290406399 288299008 137,5G Microsof 
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume5 290406400 323960831  33554432    16G Linux св
/dev/mapper/isw_chdaeggdih_RAID0IMSVolume6 323960832 500121599 176160768    84G Linux fi
```

Изначально grub вообще не показывался, потом с помощью программы `Grub Customizer` настроил чтоб показывался в принудительно, но в нем нет пункта с виндой. Что делать, подскажите.

P.S. Если нужна дополнительная информация - пишите, сразу предоставлю.

UPD: в /boot/grub/list.cfg нет ни слова про windows..
Как и в каком формате туда нужно вносить новый пункт с виндой? Может есть программы упрощающие это действо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью программы [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) все быстро пофиксится.

1) Запусти Ubuntu с флешки

2) В терминале пропиши команды :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

3) Перезагрузить...